# check if images not exist on load change src

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, url

I'm trying to change my image size with javascript to be 500x375 instead of 130x98. If there is no 500x37 for that image, than I would like it to fallback to 130x98.

So far, I have the code below. It changes my images to 500x375, but the ones that do not have that size it appears broken instead of falling back to 130x98. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```js
function ImageExists(selector) {
  var imageFound = $(selector);

  if (imageFound.height() === 0) {
    console.log('no height');
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

$('div.photo > a > img').each(function(k, v) {
  var x = v.src;
  v.src = x.replace('130x98', '500x375');

  if (!ImageExists(v)) {
    console.log(v.src);
    v.src = x.replace('500x375', '130x98')
  }
});
```

Comment: provide ImageExists function .. if this function return true or false .. so use    if (ImageExists(v) == false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var src1 = '130x98';
    var src2 = '500x375';

    $('div.photo > a > img').each(function(){
        var changeSrc;
        var Image = $(this);
        var GetSrc = $(this).attr('src');
        Image.error(function() {
           if(GetSrc.indexOf(src1) !== -1 ){
               changeSrc = GetSrc.replace(src1 , src2);
           }else if(GetSrc.indexOf(src2) !== -1 ){
               changeSrc = GetSrc.replace(src2 , src1);
           }
           Image.attr("src", changeSrc);
        });

    })
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/bjzss9Lc/7/)

Comment: @sarah yes it will change just the image src without height and width .. I will update my answer .. just wait

Comment: @sarah I really can't got your point .. you already have a search result page and you can use if statement  in your code which render images to get the images you want .. except if you need Jquery to change your img src when you hove over image

Comment: the only problem im having is getting the url to change back to 130x98 if the 500x375 image does not exist

Comment: @sarah after more time .. updated answer .. but your question and code looking for size  and what you need is to check images on load .. So your question title should be .. check if images not exist on load change src

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef: Consider using placeholder images i.e. in your examples: https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?w=250&h=150&txt=Hello+World&txtsize=42&bg=cc0e0e&txtclr=b5f4f0 You cannot rely on images that may not be around tomorrow. This is the site that generates those URLs: https://placehold.it/ ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Thanks a lot .. its very helpful :)

Comment: Thank you both, you have been very helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing semicolon in `v.src = x.replace('500x375', '130x98'):`in this line??

try putting `alert();`function in which line you doubted... `alert();` will not work if any previous line is in error

```
$('div.photo > a > img').each(function (k, v) {
       var x = v.src;
       v.src = x.replace('130x98', '500x375');
       if (!ImageExists(v)) {
           console.log(v.src);
           v.src = x.replace('500x375', '130x98');
       };
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trying the on error event instead of your ImageExists method:

```
$("img").error(function () {
  //load in your default image dimensions. 
});
```

When there's an error loading the image this will be triggered.

You might also want to unbind this event the first time it us run in case it continuously loops.